# How to find the index of two similar numbers in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7

Here is my program,

```
item_no = []
max_no = 0
for i in range(5):
    input_no = int(input("Enter an item number: "))
    item_no.append(input_no)
for i in item_no:
    if no > max_no:
       max_no = no
high = item_no.index(max_no)
print (item_no[high])
```

Example input: `5, 6, 7, 8, 8`

Example output: `8`

How can I change my program to output the same highest numbers in an array and how do I find the index of the result in (item_no)?

Expected output: `8, 8`

Expected index for the result in item_no: `3, 4`

Comment: Let's clear this: You want to find all the highest numbers in an array, put them in another array, print them and also print their indexes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `max()` to find the maximum values.

```
item_no = []
for i in range(5):
    input_no = int(input("Enter an item number: "))
    item_no.append(input_no)

m = max(item_no)
max_values = [i for i in item_no if i == m]
max_values_indexes = [i for i, j in enumerate(item_no) if j == m]

print(max_values)
print(max_values_indexes)
```

Output using `5, 6, 7, 8, 8` as input:

```
[8, 8]
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a filter function to find all max elements and than a new list for the index.

```
items = []
for i in range(5):
    no = int(input("Enter an item number: "))
    items.append(no)

max_item = max(items)
highest = list(filter(lambda x: x==max_item, items))
index = [pos for pos, no in enumerate(items) if no == highest[0]]
print (highest)
print (index)
```

With the input of 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, you'll get

```
[8, 8]
[3, 4]
```